# Recursively parse org-mode hierarchy

Tags: parsing, emacs, recursion, elisp, org-mode

I'm trying to parse org-mode text in this way:

```
* head
** sub-head
    - word :: description
** sub-head
    - word :: description
    - some notes
* head2
** sub-head2
    - some more notes
```

I am trying to capture the data (such as "word :: description" and "some notes") in such a way that each piece of data preserves what its parent headers are and what the parent's parents are, etc. I envision the data coming out in such a form in elisp:

```
(
    ("head" 
        ("sub-head" ("word :: definition")) 
        ("sub-head" ("word :: description" "some notes"))
    )
    ("head2"
        ("sub-head2" ("some more notes"))
    )
)
```

I am guessing there is an elegant solution using recursion. I'm open to structuring the data in elisp a different way, if there's a better way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a recursive solution:

```
(defun org-splitter (str lvl)
  (let* ((lst (split-string
               str
               (concat lvl " ")))
         (out (unless (= (length (car lst))
                         (length str))
                (mapcar
                 (lambda (s)
                   (and 
                    (string-match "\\([^\n]+\\)\n\\(.*\\)" s)
                    (list (match-string 1 s)
                          (org-splitter
                           (substring-no-properties
                            s (match-beginning 2))
                           (concat lvl "\\*")))))
                 (cdr lst)))))
    (if (string= (car lst) "")
        out
      (cons (car lst) out))))

(defun org-recurse-all ()
  (let ((str (buffer-substring-no-properties
              (point-min) (point-max))))
    (org-splitter str "^\\*")))
```

Answer (score 5):

The function `org-element-parse-buffer` should help. It parses the whole org-mode buffer into a lisp list. You will get more properties than you need.

http://orgmode.org/worg/exporters/org-element-docstrings.html#sec-10